# Display property of a object

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On Login page of StackOverFlow, clicking on "Log in using Stack Exchange" link makes "forgot password" link invisible so the Display property changes from block to none

forgot password

changes to

forgot password

How to verify this using getAttributes() method.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may better use [wait for Expected Conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html), like using `python`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")

#Find and click button
stack_exchange_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Log in using Stack Exchange']")
stack_exchange_button.click()

#Let's wait up to 10 seconds for forgot link to be invisible
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id='forgot-password']")))

print "Link is invisible"
```

Well, if you still don't want to use waits for expected condition, you can check that the following element exists: `//a[@id='forgot-password'][contains(@style,'display: none')]`